# encrypt and decrypt string

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have a question regarding encrypting and decrypting a string

I have to send a encrypted string over the network.(an android app is the client) this is what i did so far

```
byte[] input = getByteArray(filePath);//get the message stored in a file as a byte array
```

by going through some tutorial i managed to get the String message to a byte array and
encrypted it using javax.crypto

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
```

encrypted msg is retrived as a byte array

```
byte[] encrypted
```

i even managed to decrypt it using the reverse method and get the message again

but my problem comes when i try to convert this encrypted byte array  to strings (to pass it over the network)
and then reconvert it to a byte array

i tryed this

```
String encryptedStrn = new String(encrypted); // convert to string
```

when i convert it to the byte array by 
    byte[] enc = encryptedStrn.getBytes();

and use this enc array to decrypt but the output does not come correctly.

Have i missed some basic stuff regarding converting. Please help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `encryptedStrn.getBytes()`. Use Base64 encoding.

Comment: DES is rather weak too. Use AES instead.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I have the problem in converting bytes to string.

Comment: Not if you do what @CodeInChaos recommended, you won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As CodeInChaos wrote in a comment, you shouldn't use the `String(byte[])` constructor to create a string from opaque binary data. The string constructors are intended for *text data* which has been encoded using an encoding like ASCII, UTF-8 etc. Opaque binary data such as the result of encryption, or an image file, is *not* encoded text data in the same way, so you end up losing information.

You should use base64 instead, which encodes *any* binary data into ASCII. There are various 3rd party libraries for this, including a good [public domain one](http://iharder.net/base64). Alternatively, on Android you can just use the [`Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class.

Additionally, even when you *are* encoding or decoding real text, you shouldn't use `String.getBytes()` and the `String(byte[])` constructor anyway - they use the platform default encoding, which is almost always the wrong choice. Instead, you should use the overloads which explicitly take a `CharSet` or the name of a character encoding. UTF-8 is typically a good encoding to use if you're able to control both ends - if you're only controlling one end, you need to know which encoding the other end is expecting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Information you provided is very useful to me

Answer (score 0):

You should base64-encode the cipher text. Don't just convert it to a String. String is not a container for binary data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string EncryptUser(string userID)
    {
        using (var cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(DESKey, DESInitializationVector), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
        {
            writer.Write(userID);
            writer.Flush();
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            writer.Flush();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        }
    }


    public string DecryptUserID(string userID)
    {
        using (var cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(userID)))
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(DESKey, DESInitializationVector), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```